# How to create constant uint32 tags with four ASCII codes at compile time?

Tags: go, constants

I need to create many uint32 tags which are mapping of ASCII letters. For instance the tag "abcd" is encoded as 0x61626364 where each byte correspond to the ASCII code of the letter.

A straightforward solution is to define the tag values like this

```
type Tag uint32

const Tag_abcd = Tag(0x61626364)
```

But this is error prone.

A less error prone solution would be to define the tag values with a function receiving the letters as argument.

```
const Tag_abcd = foo("abcd")
```

or like this as can easily been done with a macro in C

```
const Tag_abcd = bar('a','b','c','d')
```

But this would require support of functions evaluated at compile time. As far as I know, it is not possible with Go. Am I correct ? Could there be another way ?

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is probably using `go generate`: https://blog.golang.org/generate

Comment: @Adrian I never used go generate. How does it work with a public package ? When a user installs the package, will go generate be called by go get ?

Comment: @chmike Generally you commit the generated code along with everything else, so that it's available when fetched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may assemble the constant using [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) and bit shifts. It won't be too compact, but it will be "safe" (meaning you can see the characters in the [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)):

```
const TagABCD Tag = 'a'<<24 + 'b'<<16 + 'c'<<8 + 'd'
```

Alternatively you may write it in multiple lines, so the letters are aligned in a column:

```
const TagABCD2 Tag = 0 +
    'a'<<24 +
    'b'<<16 +
    'c'<<8 +
    'd'
```

Comment: That is a good compromise. Very impressive. Thank you very much. BTW, can we have underscore in constant names ? The reason is that TagABCD is different from Tagabcd and I find Tag_abcd more readable. I tested it with visual studio code and it doesn’t complain about it.

Comment: You can but it's not standard go style. Go usually uses camelCase

Comment: @chmike If it compiles, you obviously can. But Go prefers `MixedCaps` or `mixedCaps` rather than underscores. [Source](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#mixed-caps).

Comment: @icza, you should revert it because it is confusing. It won’t match the requirement of the question.

Comment: @chmike Fine, I reverted to the original order. Clearing my comments...

Answer (score 1):

To expand on icza's answer, and to improve readability of the tag declaration, you can:

- declare helper constants in the form `<letter><number>`, where `<letter>` is the related ASCII character and `<number>` is the position of that char in the 4-character tag.
- bit-shift the rune by [`iota`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota)`* 8`
- compose the tag constant by OR `|`'ing the helper constants

```
import "fmt"

const (
    a1 uint32 = 'a'<<(iota*8)
    a2
    a3
    a4
)

// other similar const declarations for b1,b2,b3,b4 and so on
// must repeat the keyword const to reset iota

const Tag_abcd = a4 | b3 | c2 | d1

const Tag_ddba = d4 | d3 | b2 | a1

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", Tag_abcd) // 61626364
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", Tag_ddba) // 64646261
}
```

The advantage is that:

- the tag declaration is probably easier to read and more straightforward for human maintainers
- the helper identifiers can be easily refactored with IDE support

The disadvantage is that:

- the source might become more verbose, but you can mitigate this by isolating the helper consts into a separate file
- for uppercase ASCII, helper consts as `A1` will become exported, so then you might have to prefix the identifier with `_` or similar tricks

YMMV

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hIDDPcEVoR1)

Comment: Good to know that this is also possible. In my case there are many possible letters. It would thus make it more complex than the solution proposed by icza. When the number of letters is small (e.g. DNA) this would be a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [go generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to parse your compound constant value to different memory allocations.

it is quite complex to maintain this implementation though if you have a team that instantly needs to know what this does and when it is safe to refactor it

Comment: A reasonable answer, but [please don't paste images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: You are right, already removed it. Thank you

Comment: It's great to put code in your answer, just do it as text, not as an image.